# JQuery, функция resize()

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Есть элемент div с php-функцией внутри.

Вообщем хотелось чтобы при маленьком масштабе элемент div исчез вместе с php-функцией, и при этом появлялась кнопка при нажатии которой открывался тот самый элемент div с php-функцией как слайдер(как в Вконтакте на телефоне).

Как можно решить такую проблему. Исчезают они с помощью классов в bootstrap(visible-lg и т.д.)

Comment: Напишите более подробней что хотите. И скриншоты смотреть не удобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто. При клике на кнопку снимите класс, блокирующий отображение объекта:

```
$('#hiddenblock').toggleClass("visible-lg-block");//показать-скрыть
```

или

```
$('#hiddenblock').removeClass("visible-lg-block");//только показать
```

Затем удалите кнопку, если нужно:

```
$(this).remove();
```

```js
$('#show').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenblock').toggleClass("visible-lg-block");
})
$('#showandremove').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenblock').removeClass("visible-lg-block");
    $(this).remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="show" class="hidden-lg">
      Показать/скрыть блок
</button>

<button id="showandremove" class="hidden-lg">
      Показать и убрать кнопку
</button>

<div id="hiddenblock" class="visible-lg-block">
      Контент, спрятанный на мобильной версии
</div>
```